# Receive Seismic Data from Geosig Ve-53

Tags: python, sensors, pci, data-acquisition

I'm aiming to creat a small data acquisition system that collect data from a Geosig Ve-53 using KPCI-3101 as a physical interface; and python to creat an application that record events and visualize it.

The Ve-53 is using 12 Pins Cable as shown in the table :
[ve-53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By7zK.jpg)

My questions :

- Is it possible to do this with only the available materials ?
- Will i need more than only python to receive, store and visualize data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, after looking on internet for work-arounds; using QuickDAQ or Pydaqmx mixed with Python will do the job.